# Simplest way to heatmap selected columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['a','b','c','d','e'],
              "year": ['2012','2013','2010','2008','2011'],
              "value": ['10','22','7','8','32']})
```

What's a simple way to apply heatmap only to the value column? I want to avoid year being heatmapped.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                  "year": ['2012','2013','2010','2008','2011'],
                  "value": ['254','220','275','283','323'],
                    "age": ['42','32','27','28','32']})
```

Same question, but for both value and age individually - i.e I want each column to be heatmapped separately and scaled to that column (so age doesn't show as all one extreme and value the other extreme).

I have so many convoluted snippets of code for achieving this, but often times I just copy paste into excel because it's way faster...are there quick & clean ways to this basic selective heatmapping in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in a notebook or somewhere you can render HTML, you can use the `style` accessor of a dataframe along w/ `background_gradient`. Seaborn makes it very easy to generate colormaps for this purpose.

You can specify the columns you want to apply the colormap to using the `subset` argument.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                  "year": ['2012','2013','2010','2008','2011'],
                  "value": ['254','220','275','283','323'],
                    "age": ['42','32','27','28','32']})

df2["value"] = pd.to_numeric(df2["value"])
df2["age"] = pd.to_numeric(df2["age"])

cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
df2.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=["value", "age"])
```

[image]

If you want different colors or specify separate `vmin`/`vmax` to columns, you can simply call `background_gradient` multiple times.

```
green_cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
blue_cm = sns.light_palette("blue", as_cmap=True)

(df2.style
 .background_gradient(cmap=blue_cm, subset="value", vmin=200, vmax=400)
 .background_gradient(cmap=green_cm, subset="age", vmin=0, vmax=50))
```

[image]